# webscraping via excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

i want to scrape the last row (starting with 'Recom') from the table in https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=amzn

Unfortunately my code errors with: Object variable or With block variable not set, in the output section of the code Children(x).

Can you please help me to understand why the code errors even if the html hierarchy is respected?

Thanks!

```
Dim y As Long
Dim x As String
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim elem As Object, tRow As Object, S$, R&



lastrow = Sheets("Table5").usedrange.Row - 1 + Sheets("Table5").usedrange.Rows.Count

For y = 11 To lastrow Step 2

x = Sheets("Table5").Range("A" & y).Value
If x = "" Then
Exit Sub
Else
'On Error Resume Next

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=" & x, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        .write S
        
        For Each elem In .getElementsByTagName("tr")
        
        If InStr(elem.innerText, "Recom") > 0 Then

        Sheets("Table5").Range("AD" & y) = elem.Children(1).innerText
        Sheets("Table5").Range("AE" & y) = elem.Children(3).innerText
        
        End If
        Next elem
        
    End With
    
End If
Next y
```

Comment: If you consider the row containing `Recom`, there are several tds within it. Which text out of those tds you wanna grab?

Comment: i want the values right next to the respective names: so 1.7 (recom), -0.11% (SMA20) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it's appears to be an easy fix. You need to look for the `tr` which starts with `Recom`. The `Like` operator is exactly doing the same that I tried to say

```
Sub FetchContent()
    Const Url$ = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=amzn"
    Dim elem As Object, tRow As Object, S$, R&

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
        .Send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        .write S
        For Each elem In .getElementsByTagName("tr")
            If elem.innerText Like "Recom*" Then
                R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = elem.Children(0).innerText
                Cells(R, 2) = elem.Children(1).innerText
                Cells(R, 3) = elem.Children(2).innerText
                Cells(R, 4) = elem.Children(3).innerText
                Cells(R, 5) = elem.Children(4).innerText
                Cells(R, 6) = elem.Children(5).innerText
                Cells(R, 7) = elem.Children(6).innerText
                Exit For
            End If
        Next elem
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sim, how to deal with 'no result' tickers: e.g.
https://finviz.com/search.ashx?p=AEGG

a dialogue box is popping up saying 'you'll need a new app to open this about' everytime a 'no result' ticker is in place.

Application.DisplayAlerts = False doesn't helpt, since its a Windows 10 notification...

How can i skip this? THANKS!

Comment: I use win 7. When I run the script using the url in your comment, I didn't encounter any error. It just populates no result when the execution is done.